# MYSQL results which contains strings but returns a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I run this SQL code and it displays me, result = 60
I did not understand why it returns me the sum of the variables while the @Result variable contains strings

```
SET @data_code = 10;
set @env_code = 20;
set @Id = 30;

set @Result = @data_code + '-' + @env_code + '-FrontEnd' + @Id;
select @Result
```

Comment: The `+` operator is implicitely casting the string to a number and ignoring anything that is not a number.

Comment: MySQL uses the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings, not `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT()`

```
SET @data_code = 10;
set @env_code = 20;
set @Id = 30;

set @Result = CONCAT(@data_code,'-',@env_code,'-FrontEnd',@Id);
select @Result
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/251906